# Jooq how to query entity based on composite key

Tags: java, sql, jooq, composite-key

How to query an entity based on a composite key in Jooq?
E.g.:

```
UserAttempts org.jooq.impl.DAOImpl.findById(Record2<UInteger, String> id)
```

`id` is a composite key. How to use the `Record2<UInteger, String>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can construct a `Record2` using [`DSLContext.newRecord()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-):

```
UserAttempts attempts =
dao.findById(ctx.newRecord(USER_ATTEMPTS.ID_COLUMN1, USER_ATTEMPTS.ID_COLUMN2)
                .values(uint(1), "abc"));
```